# Proof of Cauchy Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $G$ is a group of order $n$, and $p$ is a prime dividing $n$ then $G$ has an element of order $p$.

**Proof:** Consider the action of a cyclic group $C=\langle T\rangle$ of order $p$ on $X=\{(a_1,\cdots,a_p):a_1\cdots a_p=e\}\subset G_1\times\cdots\times G_p$ given by

$$\tau(a_1,\dots,a_p)=(a_p,a_1,\cdots,a_{p-1}) \\
\tau^2(a_1,\dots,a_p)=(a_{p-1},a_p,\cdots,a_{p-2}) \\ \cdots$$

To check this action is well-defined, we need to check that if $a_1\cdots a_p=e$, then $a_2\cdots a_p a_1=e$ because if $a_1\cdots a_p=e$ then $a^{-1}(a_1,\cdots,a_p)a_1=a_1^{-1}ea_1=a_2\cdots a_1=e$ .

We know that if $x=(a_1,\cdots,a_p)\in X$ then $|O(x)|=\frac{|G|}{|G_x|}=\frac{p}{|G_x|}$ where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$. Also, $C_x$ has order 1 or $p$ by Lagrange. Now:

(1) If $G_x=1$ then $|O(x)|=p$ (**And then??? Orbit is not a subgroup???**)

(2) If $|G_x|=p$ then $G_x=G$, $|O(x)|=1$, i.e., $x$ is a fixed point of $G$. This means $x=(a_1,\cdots,a_p)=\tau(x)=(a_p,\cdots a_{p-1})$. Thus $G$ has element of order $p\iff\exists$ a fixed point for action on $X$ other than $(e,\cdots,e)$ (**Why???**)

Suppose there are $k$ orbits in $X$ of order $p$ and $m$ orbits of order 1 (fixed points). Our goal is to show that $m\geq2$.

$|X|=kp+m$ "orbit partitions $X$"

$|X|=n^{p-1}$ (**Why???**) free to choose $a_1,\cdots,a_{p-1}$ in $G$ in an arbitrary fashion and let $a_p=(a_1,\cdots,a_{p-1})^{-1}$. We have $n^{p-1}=kp+m$ since $p$ divides $n$, $p$ divides $m$ as well. Since $m\geq 1$ this shows that $m\geq p>1$ Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be three questions:

- It doesn't matter that it is not a subgroup, it is one of the orbits, they partition $X$.
- Notice that if the element $\{x,x,x\dots,x\}\in X$ this means that $x^p=e$ and since $p$ is a prime this means $x$ is the identity or $x$ has order $p$.
- They explain why right after you ask the question. The idea is that Every element of $X$ is of the form $(a_1,a_2,\dots, a_{p-1},a_p)$ such that $a_1a_2\dots a_p=e$. In other words if and only if $a_p=(a_1a_2\dots a_{p-1})^{-1}$. So no matter how you select the first $p-1$ elements there is exactly one way to select $a_n$ so that the product is equal to $e$ (and there are clearly $|G|^{p-1}$ ways to select the first $p-1$ elements freely).